# Center a fixed UIView inside a UIScrollView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I understood the operation of the `UIScrollView` with *AutoLayout*, but in all cases I saw on the internet, I did not find a similar problem with this, maybe that's why the solutions are not working properly.

My scenario is this:

```
Scroll View
   Content View
      Login View
```

Where **Login View** I need a fixed width/height, vertically and horizontally center. And here the constraints that I set:

[image: Constraints that I set]

The problem is: when I rotate simulator (iPhone 6s) to landscape, I can't scroll and view everything because the content size of scroll view is 375 and my login box height is 420.

Is there something I'm missing for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Your constraints should be like,

`ScrollView` - `top,bottom,leading,trailing`

`ContentView (UIView)` - `top,bottom,leading,trailing,fixed height,horizontally center in container(center X)`

`LoginView` - `fixed width,fixed height, horizontally center in container(center X) and vertically center in container (center Y)`

Answer (score 0):

try this small video tutorial that I created for you. It shows how to setup `scrollview` that work for any `ios device` + work for any `orientation` mode. tutorial is written in `objective c`, but doesn't matter concept is same. less coding, just one `method` + `autolayout.`

link to the video tutorial --- > [setup scrollview for any ios device + for any orientation mode in ios](http://iosfirst.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-setup-scrollview-that-fits-for.html)

hope this will help to you.try this and enjoy....